# Periodicity of Fredholm operators for proving Bott periodicity

Tags: topological-k-theory, k-theory

In proving the periodicity of Fredholm operator Fred$_0(H)$ $\cong$ Fred$_{-2}(H)$ for proving Bott periodicity Dan Freed in his [notes](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/dafr/M392C/Notes/lecture12.pdf) commented that (proposition 12.46)

\begin{equation*}
     \begin{aligned}
      \text{Fred}_0(V^* \otimes H) &\longrightarrow \text{Fred}_{-2}(H) \subset \text{Fred}_0(V \otimes V^* \otimes H) \\
       A &\longmapsto \text{id}_V \otimes A
     \end{aligned}
    \end{equation*}
                by the fact that the only central endomorphisms of $V$ are multiples of id$_V$, where $V$ is a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-graded complex vector space with dimension 1 for both the even and odd components.

I really don't understand how this fact can lead to the claimed homeomorphism.  Could somebody clarify for me?